# Should I use a Apple Card or any credit card recommendations?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card

I heard about a Apple card, which has no fees about of any kind. But however, I just want just a plain simple credit card that I can just buy it now and pay the next day or two. Simple as that. Not that I want to use on something that's too much, but just something when I can't afford right now, I can just buy now and pay the next day.

For instance: I was willing to buy a coffee maker (making it up as example), I'm a few dollars short until the next day. So I can use a credit card to buy it now, I get paid the next day, and I can pay in full the very next day.

If a Apple Card doesn't sound suitable to my benefits, are there any recommendations I should look into? I just want a plan simple card that I can buy it now and pay the next day. I don't want no APR, or any complicated stuff that I am gonna have trouble with. Also, I don't want to use a credit card on a everyday use.

Comment: This is more of a "how do credit cards work" question, and so if anything should have been Closed - **Duplicate**, since there are a number of questions on whether you can pay of cards immediately.

Comment: You can buy the coffee maker with *any* credit card and make a payment tomorrow, even if you have the money today.

Comment: You should just wait until tomorrow to buy your coffee maker. Don't get into the habit of spending money you don't have yet. Even better, you should have enough savings to buy a coffee maker...

Answer (score 2):

> But however, I just want just a plain simple credit card that I can just buy it now and pay the next day or two.

The Apple Card **is** a credit card, specifically a MasterCard, and has no fees.

> I just want a plan simple card that I can buy it now and pay the next day.

Just like every other credit card (in the US, at least, there's nothing stopping you from making a payment on your Apple Card a day or two after a purchase.  (That is, in fact, exactly what I did when we were still breaking ourselves from the habit of spending willy nilly.  After putting our credit cards "in the back of the sock drawer", we paid everything with a debit card.  That lasted about a year.  After that, we started using the CC, but every evening I'd make a payment on any purchases that day.  That got really old pretty fast, so now I pay off the card every Sunday night.  In fact, I made a payment just a few hours ago.)

> I don't want no APR, or any complicated stuff that I am gonna have trouble with.

If you always pay off your CC, it does not matter what the interest rate is, because there's no balance on which to charge interest...

Comment: so just simply, if I just make a simple payment on the card, and pay it the next day, I won't have to worry on anything else?

Comment: @mikey186 you'll have to worry about **tracking** what you spent yesterday, since the charges *might* not yet show up in your account.  (Chase is good about quickly showing pending charges, but Bank of America is a bit slow.) And some banks only let you make one payment per day.  This is why I track what I spend in a spreadsheet, and then pay "last week's charges" on Sunday night.